# how to deploy a slim rest API on shared hosting/cPanel/go-daddy

Tags: cpanel, slim

I am building a rest API using slim framework . everything works perfectly on my local machine .

Any one tell me the steps to how to deploy a slim rest API on shared hosting/cPanel/go-daddy

Where i put my URL

file name

index.php
.htaccess
dbconnect

Answer (score 0):

- Basically, you have to rename your `public` folder to `public_html`.
- *"...when you upload your files, your `.htaccess` and `index.php` files that were previously in your public folder will now go into the `public_html` folder."*  (tflight answer)

**Answer based on:** [How to deploy slim on a shared host](http://discourse.slimframework.com/t/deploying-on-a-shared-host/1246/4)

If doesn't work please give us more details, how is your folder structure? what the logs file said? what do you mean with "where i put my URL?"

Answer (score 0):

**Slim Framework 4**

For Slim version 4 the following line must be added in the index file inside the public folder, located in the root of the application.

**folder** public/index.php

**add line:**

$app->setBasePath('/foldeHosting');

[image]